# Run function after user stops typing

Tags: jquery, debouncing

In my application i want to update a google maps map based on the adres and place a user types.
Because i dont want the application to change the map everytime the user types 1 letter i searched for something to lower the ammount off function calls. Because time out will only delay the call to the function ( the function will be called the same times as if it had no delay), I searched for alternatives and found [jQUery debounce](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/), i tryed to implement it like:

```
$('input.locatie-input').on('input', $.debounce(function () {
        console.log('changed');
        initializeMap();
    }, 500));
```

but i keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

reffering to the following line:

```
 $('input.locatie-input').on('input', $.debounce(function () {
```

What am i doing wrong, and is debounce the way to go in this situation ?

**UPDATE:**

Roko C. Buljan's answer is working, the debounce plugin does the same

debounce plugin code:

```
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
var timeout;
return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
};
};
```

Comment: have you included the debounce javascript on your page?

Comment: You don't need any *debounce* plugin for that task.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan but the reason why the OP's code wasn't working was because he was missing the plugin code right?

Comment: You are right @NathanKoop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this: ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vucubu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
var timeo;                                         // Define timeout var.
$('input.locatie-input').on('input', function(){   // As one types
    clearTimeout(timeo);                           // clear a running timeout
    timeo = setTimeout(initializeMap, 500);        // and set a new one
});
```

Comment: this will only set a delay, so the times it wil run the initializemap function is equal to the same code without the delay right? What i want do do is limit the calls to the function, EDIT mm the jsbin shows it does not, why not ?

Comment: @SvenB there will be only one function call as you can see in the Demo link, and only once after one stops typing, after 500ms. If one starts typing again, great, the same will happen over and over.

Comment: @SvenB cause as you type clearTimeout clears the currently running timeout setting another one.

Comment: Sound like what i need, but what is the use for debounce than if I may ask, it sounds too mee its a short version of the code you posted. THX for the help btw

Comment: @SvenB can you show me the whole *debounce Plugin* code please? I'm really interested if the **Debounce Plugin** is shorter that the code above.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ is what i found, the most articles i found look pretty old (most 2011) but i cant find that the function debounce is no lonoger existing.

Answer (score 1):

David Walsh has an excellent write-up about debouncing. Roko is correct however.

http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce